# Express analysis of deviance table as ANOVA

Tags: anova, variance

How can I express the following analysis of deviance in an ANOVA table , by hand not with R..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a classical analysis of variance table from this as it has tested the terms sequentially. That is to say size:side is adjusted for all the others including size:type but size:type is only adjusted for the main effects and each main effect is only adjusted for the ones preceding it in the table not for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Degrees of freedom = 27 (35 - 8)
Residual sum of squares = 668.8 (the residual deviance of size:side)

MS = 668.8/27

Then just set up the ANOVA table, for example with size:type;

Factor  size:type

SS      804.2

DF      2

MS      402.1

F       402.1/(668.8/27)

And continue for each interaction

Then just do these for each interaction